# In what cases Jinns can attack humans?

Tags: practical-islam, jinn

One of my relatives was doing itikaf. And for some reason, they weren't able to complete doing it, and now they're behaving like a mental patient and saying stuff like "I can see a person (Jinn) wanting to kill me". And much more. I took them to a mental hospital but the doctors don't seem to understand what happened, and my relative didn't get well. Ultimately I think it's really some Jinn(s) attacking them.

Does that mean not doing itikaf fully will cause attacks by Jinns?
Also, in what cases a Jinn can attack a human? Is there any way described in the Quran to save myself (and my relative) from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whosoever for Allah’s sake did even one day's Itikaf, Allah would keep
> him away from Jahannam (hellfire) by trenches.
>
> — Prophet Muhammad (sallallahu alayhi wasallam), [Tabarani]

According to the hadith, even if you do itkaaf one day, Allah will keep you away from jahnnam. The primary goal of itkaf is to focus only on Allah's worship by eradicating all distractions. Itkaf is a defence against jahnnam and all other forms of evil.

It's crucial for us to be aware of the prerequisites for Jinn to possess your body.

> 1. When someone is so enraged that the jinn enters their body as a result of their excessive rage. One should sit down when he is angry,
>    as what the Prophet(saw) said.
> 2. The jinn may enter if someone is really frightened or terrified of something.
> 3. Ignoring Allah, as by neglecting to perform adkar.

Not doing itkaf doesn't mean that the jinn will attack you.